# Singly linked list, deleting k element

Tags: algorithm, list, pseudocode

I want to delete k number element from list. I would do it like below (pseudocode)

```
delete(L,k)

x <- L.head
i <- 1
while(i < k-1 AND x.next != NULL)
    x<-x.next
    i <- i+1
if(i = k-1 AND x.next != NULL)
    if(x.next.next != NULL)
        x.next <- x.next.next
    else if(x.next.next = NULL)
        x.next = NULL
```

My purpose is: if k is last, then delete k-1.next. If k is not last, then make k-1.next pointing to k+1. Is it good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linked list delete method seems mostly correct.

Why are you counting from one? Do you want the head to be a dummy node, which contains no value (then you can keep an empty list) if so try:

```
i=0
while(i <= k && x.next != null)
```

Then when you want to delete the first item (k=1) the while loop will execute once. Otherwise use

```
while(i = k && x.next !=null)
```

Similarly in the first if statement change `k-1` to `k`.

I don't know why you use the IF ELSE, because if it x.next.next is null you are just assigning null anyway.

The problem is with your counter values vs the delete values. Try deleting the first item of your list.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that L.head should be empty?

Comment: And next thing: if loop continues until i=k, and then we delete k.next, we delete k+1 element, dont we?

Comment: I mean if you want you could make L.head always empty as one way to create an empty linked list (a list containing only the head). Otherwise when you delete the only item in the list you have no list. You don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. How about my second question: "if loop continues until i=k, and then we delete k.next, we delete k+1 element, dont we?" :)

Comment: Yeah I messed up your k analogy. I'm too tired to look at it right now, but you need to fix it so you can delete at k=1 (or k=0) whatever you choose to be the first element.

Comment: I think just i = 0 might be all you need to do